# ReactJS : Edit Textbox which has already value in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. I am stuck in one problem. I get textbox value from calling API which has predefined value. but When I try to edit its value then it is not letting me to edit.

```js
class TextEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      emailIdValue: ""
    };
  }

  onKeyPress = e => {
    const regEx = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (e.target.value === "" || !regEx.test(e.target.value)) {
    
    } else {
      this.setState({
        emailIdValue: e.target.value
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value="this.props.getValue"
          onChange={e => this.keyPress(e)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I get **abc@xyz.com** in `this.props.getValue` .

How can I edit the textbox value.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: You have bound the onChange event to a function that does not exist. It should be onChange={this.onKeyPress}.

Comment: Actually your prop and state don't have any type of connection. So in order to render UI, you should update state. Then there is always a re-render operation performed when `setState` gets executed

Comment: Also your onKeyPress function has invalid syntax. It is a method of your class. So it should be onKeyPress(e) { at the beginning.

Comment: And the value attribute on the input should be written with curly braces around it instead of quotes like so: value={this.props.getValue}.

Comment: @SimeonSmith His `onKeyPress` is not invalid syntax. That is a property initialized arrow function.

Comment: @Tholle I'm not referring to the arrow function. I'm referring to the fact that he has it named keyPress not onKeyPress. Also while the arrow function is fine it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the `this.props.getValue` value in the `TextEditor` component state when you create it and change that instead:

```
class TextEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      emailIdValue: props.getValue
    };
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.emailIdValue}
          onChange={this.onKeyPress}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Way to go!

Comment: oh yeah.. that's great. I can do that.. thank you so much. Accepting answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: hello. I can't edit the textbox from your given answer. It allows me to edit only one character back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've found the answer. But I created this small fiddle to help anyone who have same problem. You have following problems in your code.
`value="this.props.getValue"` this is not right way to do this. You are setting value equal to string not equal to expression. It should be like this `value={this.props.getValue}`
secondly, you were referring wrong function name on `onChange` event. It should be like this `onChange={e => this.onKeyPress(e)}`

In the end, like @Tholle said, you can set your state value with your props. And then set the value of text box from state so that whenever you'll write something, state will udpate and so will be your textbox value.

Following Code Sand Box will help you.

**[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0poj64100l)**